# Как определить размер функции в программе?

Tags: c++, c

В коде имеется функция. Хочу инжектировать эту функцию в чужой процесс, но чтобы выделить под нее память в процессе нужно знать ее размер в байтах. Как это можно сделать?

Comment: что имеется ввиду под _размером_ функции?

Comment: размер в байтах. функцию нужно инжектировать в чужой процесс, но вот как вычислить ее размер, чтобы выделить под нее память не знаю

Comment: вам стоит развернуть свой вопрос

Comment: @Abyx, Тогда стоит оформить его ответом :-)

Comment: А автоматическом режиме затруднительно. Но очень легко после компиляции посмотреть в Иде.

Comment: вот в том то и дело, что размер нужно определять автоматически :(

Comment: Функции для внедрения вынесете в отдельную DLL и уже ее внедряйте. Тогда вам не понадобится считать никакие-либо размеры, только адреса функций.

Comment: У меня программа сейчас именно в таком виде, но сейчас нужно именно избавиться от DLL и функцию инжектить прям из кода программы

Answer (score 3):

Функция в С/С++ не обязана быть непрерывной последовательностью инструкций машинного кода с четко выраженным началом и концом. Если несколько функций содержат одинаковый завершающий блок кода ("эпилог"), оптимизирующий компилятор может включить его в бинарник только в одной функции, а в других заменить его на инструкцию перехода в первую. В таком случае понятие "размер функции" становится неоднозначным. Кроме того, попытка перенести машинный код из одного процесса в другой "как есть" скорее всего закончится неудачей, ведь инструкции часто оперируют относительными адресами. Более правильным решением было бы реализовать инжектируемый блок кода полностью в виде ассемблерной вставки, как например [здесь](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/751021/240512).

Тем не менее, API для получения размера функции (как справочной информации) существуют. Например, так это можно сделать в Windows с помощью dbghelp:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include "DbgHelp.h"
#pragma comment(lib, "Dbghelp.lib")

struct Function {
    const char* name;
    unsigned int size;
    bool success;
};

BOOL CALLBACK EnumSymProc(PSYMBOL_INFO pSymInfo, ULONG SymbolSize, PVOID context) {

    Function* pfstruct = (Function*)context;    

    if (strcmp(pSymInfo->Name, pfstruct->name) == 0) {

        pfstruct->size = SymbolSize;
        pfstruct->success = true;       
        return FALSE; //закончить поиск

    }
    return TRUE; //продолжить поиск
}

// Находит размер функции fname и помещает в переменную resultvar
// Требует наличия отладочных символов (PDB-файла) в каталоге с программой
bool GetFunctionSize(const char* fname, unsigned int& resultvar) {

    bool ret;
    Function fstruct;
    fstruct.name = fname;
    fstruct.size = 0;
    fstruct.success = false;

    HANDLE hProcess = GetCurrentProcess(); //текущий процесс
    char Mask[] = "*!"; //искать среди всех модулей
    BOOL status;

    status = SymInitialize(hProcess, NULL, TRUE); //загрузка символов
    if (status == FALSE)
    {
        printf("SymInitialize failed. Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
        return false;
    }

    //поиск символов
    if (SymEnumSymbols(hProcess, 0, Mask, &EnumSymProc, (void*)&fstruct))
    {
        if (fstruct.success != false) {

            resultvar = fstruct.size; //возвращаем размер
            ret = true; 
        }
        else {
            printf("Symbol [%s] not found\n", fname);
            ret = false; 
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf("SymEnumSymbols failed. Error code: %d\n", GetLastError());
        ret = false;
    }

    SymCleanup(hProcess);
    return ret;
}

//**********************************

void Func() {
    printf("Hello, World!\n"); 
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    uintptr_t p = (uintptr_t)&Func;
    printf("Func address: 0x%x\n", (UINT)p);    

    unsigned int size = 0;
    if (GetFunctionSize("Func", size) != false) {
        printf("Func size: %u bytes", size);
    }

    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

При использовании Visual Studio 2017+ для корректной работы данного кода необходимо собирать проект с параметром `/DEBUG:FULL` (см. [/DEBUG](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/debug-generate-debug-info?view=vs-2019)).

Answer (score 2):

Универсального решения не существует. Особенно если вы пишите на C++. А вообще, вот занимательное чтиво прямо на тему твоего вопроса: https://rsdn.ru/forum/cpp/2333802.hot

Если коротко, то можно попытаться так:

```
static int test_proc()
{
    return 1;
}

static void size_proc()
{}

static size_t test_proc_size()
{
    return (uintptr_t)((uintptr_t)(void*)size_proc - (uintptr_t)(void*)test_proc);
}
```

но вообще никаких гарантий, особенно в том, что `size_proc` так и останется сразу за `test_proc`.

Ну и в развитие данной темы: можно попробовать получить адреса всех символов, отсортировать по возрастанию, размер между твоей функцией и следующим символом вполне может оказаться искомой величиной.