# Инжект кода в новый процесс

Tags: windows, любой-язык, x86

Как запустить процесс (x32) и выполнить в нем какой-то код,
например `MessageBoxA(0, "Hi", 0, 0)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Пример на С++ (MSVC), используется `RtlRemoteCall`:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <iostream>

typedef DWORD  __stdcall RtlRemoteCall_t(
  HANDLE Process, HANDLE Thread, PVOID CallSite,
  ULONG ArgumentCount, PULONG Arguments,
  BOOL PassContext, BOOL AlreadySuspended);
HMODULE ntdll = ::GetModuleHandleA("ntdll");
auto pRtlRemoteCall = (RtlRemoteCall_t*)::GetProcAddress(ntdll, "RtlRemoteCall");

void inject(HANDLE hProcess, HANDLE hThread) {
  char* shellcode_start;
  char* shellcode_end;
  __asm {
      mov shellcode_start, offset shellcode_start_label
      mov shellcode_end, offset shellcode_end_label
      jmp shellcode_end

  shellcode_start_label:
      mov ebx, esp // compiler would warn if we'd use EBP
                   // [ebx + 0]  context address (added by RtlRemoteCall)
                   // [ebx + 4]  arg0: NtContinue address
                   // [ebx + 8]  arg1: MessageBoxA address

      // MessageBoxA(0, "Hi", 0, 0)
      push 0
      push 0
      call hi_end_label
      _emit 'H'
      _emit 'i'
      _emit 0
  hi_end_label:
      push 0
      call dword ptr[ebx + 8]

      // NtContinue(ctx, 0)
      push 0
      push dword ptr[ebx + 0]
      call dword ptr[ebx + 4]
  shellcode_end_label:
  }

  auto shellcode_size = shellcode_end - shellcode_start;
  void* remote_ptr = ::VirtualAllocEx(hProcess, nullptr, shellcode_size,
      MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE);
  std::cout << "remote_ptr = " << remote_ptr << '\n';

  ::WriteProcessMemory(hProcess, remote_ptr, shellcode_start, shellcode_size, nullptr);

  ULONG args[] = {
    (ULONG)::GetProcAddress(ntdll, "NtContinue"),
    (ULONG)::GetProcAddress(::LoadLibraryA("user32"), "MessageBoxA"),
  };
  pRtlRemoteCall(hProcess, hThread, remote_ptr, _countof(args), args, true, true);

  ::ResumeThread(hThread);
}

int main() {
  wchar_t cmd[] = LR"(c:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe)";

  PROCESS_INFORMATION process_info;
  STARTUPINFOW startup_info;
  ::GetStartupInfoW(&startup_info);
  ::CreateProcessW(cmd, cmd, nullptr, nullptr, FALSE, CREATE_SUSPENDED,
      nullptr, nullptr, &startup_info, &process_info);
  inject(process_info.hProcess, process_info.hThread);
}
```

Обработка ошибок и закрытие хендлов убраны для простоты кода.

Answer (score 2):

Та же идея что и на С++, но теперь **Python3**, для x32

```
import binascii, ctypes, struct


def run_and_inject(target_path, code):
  si = (ctypes.c_byte * 68)(0)
  ctypes.windll.kernel32.GetStartupInfoW(si)

  cmd = ctypes.c_wchar_p(target_path)
  CREATE_SUSPENDED = 4
  pi = (ctypes.c_void_p * 4)(0)
  ctypes.windll.kernel32.CreateProcessW(cmd, cmd, 0, 0, False, CREATE_SUSPENDED, 0, 0, si, pi)

  MEM_COMMIT = 0x1000
  PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE = 0x40
  addr = ctypes.windll.kernel32.VirtualAllocEx(pi[0], 0, len(code), MEM_COMMIT, PAGE_EXECUTE_READWRITE)

  ctypes.windll.kernel32.WriteProcessMemory(pi[0], addr, code, len(code), 0)

  ctypes.windll.ntdll.RtlRemoteCall(pi[0], pi[1], addr, 0, 0, True, True)

  ctypes.windll.kernel32.ResumeThread(pi[1])


def hex2code(code_hex):
  return binascii.a2b_hex(code_hex.replace(' ', '').encode())


def push_string(str_bytes):
  return struct.pack('<BI', 0xE8, len(str_bytes) + 1) + str_bytes + b'\0'


def call(func):
  addr = ctypes.cast(func, ctypes.c_void_p).value
  return struct.pack('<BIBB', 0xB8, addr, 0xFF, 0xD0)


code = hex2code(
  # [esp + 0] is the context address (added by RtlRemoteCall)
  '89 E5' # mov ebp, esp
  # MessageBoxA(0, "Injected message", 0, 0)
  '6A 00' # push 0
  '6A 00' # push 0
  ) + push_string(b'Injected message') + hex2code(
  '6A 00' # push 0
  ) + call(ctypes.windll.user32.MessageBoxA) + hex2code(
  # NtContinue(ctx, 0)
  '6A 00' # push 0
  'FF 75 00' # push dword[ebp+0]
  ) + call(ctypes.windll.ntdll.NtContinue)

run_and_inject(r'c:\Windows\SysWOW64\notepad.exe', code)
```

Comment: Неплохо, идея собирать машинный код с помощью `struct` просто отличная. Чтобы не убирать пробелы, можно вместо `binascii.a2b_hex` использовать метод `bytes.fromhex`, например `bytes.fromhex('30 30')` превратится просто в `b'00'`.