# Инъекция DLL в свой процесс C++

Tags: c++

Учу С++. Интересен способ инъекции DLL в свой процесс.
Нашёл библиотеку [смотреть на codepad](https://codepad.remoteinterview.io/GXCSXVMKOM), делает Inject в сторонний процесс, посредством вызова CreateProcess

```
 CreateProcessW(NULL, Path, NULL, NULL, FALSE, CREATE_DEFAULT_ERROR_MODE | CREATE_SUSPENDED, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
 if (ok)
            {
                DbgPrint("CreateProcessW ok, %d", pi.dwProcessId);
                ok = (NO_ERROR == AcInjectDll(&pi, CREATE_SUSPENDED, TRUE));
                //AcInjectDll(&pi, CREATE_SUSPENDED, TRUE);
                DbgPrint("AcInjectDll %s", ok ? "ok" : "FAIL");
                CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
                CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
            }
            else
                DbgPrint("CreateProcessW FAIL");
```

Но, функция после отработки отдает fail. Конечно, при этом никакой DLL'ки не прогрузилось, а поток остался зависшим у вызываемого процесса.

Где может быть ошибка? За ранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Чтобы загрузить DLL в свой процесс, не нужна никакая "инъекция". Для этого достаточно использовать функцию [LoadLibrary](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684175%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396).

Об "инъекции DLL" говорят, когда нужно заставить чужой процесс загрузить вашу DLL. Для этих целей нельзя использовать CreateProcess (эта функция делает только то, что написано - создает процесс). Это можно сделать несколькими способами, например [с использованием WriteProcessMemory и CreateRemoteThread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22750112/dll-injection-with-createremotethread) или [RtlRemoteCall](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/751020/%D0%98%D0%BD%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%82-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0-%D0%B2-%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B9-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%86%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%81).