# Функции C++ в памяти

Tags: c++, ram

Как-то во время отладки я задался вопросом.
Почему байты по адресу пользовательских функций имеют вид "e9 .. .. .. .. e9 .. .. .. .. e9 .. .. .. .."?
Предоставлю несколько картинок ниже. 1 - байты по адресу моей функции, 2 - байты по адресу некой функции WinAPI

[image: My function]

[image: WinAPI function]

Для меня это кажется странным, то что в пользовательских функциях всегда происходит куда-то переход. Нигде объяснений этому я не нашел. 
И еще вопрос, как узнать размер какой-либо функции? К примеру чтобы скопировать ее байты `memcpy`, или же такое не представляется возможным?

Comment: Дизассемблером посмотрите, что за инструкция этот e9. Это может быть промежуточная прокладка-переход на реальное тело функции, которая существует, чтобы облегчить подмену функции отладчиком во время выполнения (edit&continue). Насчет размера функции: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/490470/

Comment: маш. коды смотрятся в описании процессоров в разделе `Instruction set`. В C/C++ нет возможности определить размер функции, но некоторые системы программирования генерят в  конце функции extern метки, по ним можно расчитать размер

Comment: http://ref.x86asm.net/coder32.html — jmp'ы, похоже...

Comment: На самом деле код функции находится в разделяемой библиотеке (.so или .dll). В момент линковки он не известен, поэтому линкер делает код заглушки, которая начинается с команды jmp на функцию, которая вычислит реальный адрес требуемой функции из .so в данном адресном  пространстве и заменит адрес в этом jmp на требуемый при первом обращении к функции.